# Group policies - WSUS

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy, wsus

I am really lost as to what is the reason as to why my group policy is not working on my domain. I have setup a GPO for my wsus server to a specific OU in my domain. It seems as of right now, none of my machines have inherited that GPO. I have manually put it in quite a few computers.

Most of my computers in the domain are linked up to my wsus server, but all my desired settings are not there.

If I run gpresult /R, On one computer I ran this on, it is linking to my backup domain controller and not my main. On another computer I checked this on, it is linking to my main DC, but it did no inherit the GPO.

When looking on my DC on gpmc - I see the policy is forced to the OU as #1 precedence.

Thank for any help.

Comment: There are no "backup" or "main" domain controller computers in Active Directory. They're all just domain controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How long have you waited, it takes up an hour for GPO to apply, and up to 22 hours for WU to connect to WSUS.

Try running `gpupdate /force /boot` on a client (warning, it'll reboot). That should force it to pull all the latest GPO settings from the nearest DC.

Which specific settings are you missing?

(Also, GPO presidence is only within the scope you're currently viewing. Other GPOs can still override it. If you have more than one GPO specifying WSUS settings, they could be overriding; if that's the case, list out what type of container their attached to an we can help you arrange the actual order.)

Answer (score 1):

I assume the PC's are in the OU that you have the GPO applied to. If not, that's a problem.

Have you tried running "gpupdate" on a client machine? If you are on a gig network and it sits for a few seconds "refreshing policy" then typically it is grabbing the new policy. If it flashes up and down real fast, then it didn't grab anything. Then you can use "wuauclt -dectectnow" and "wuauclt -reportnow" on a client machine to force it to check for updates and report to the WSUS server.

If gpupdate grabs the new policy then I would check sites and services -> sites -> intersites transport -> properties to see what "replicate every" is set to, and you may want to lower than number. 15 minutes is the default I think.

If gpupdate doesn't grab the new policy I would check sites and services to make sure than the DC's all have the correct NTDS connections.

Also check the default domain policy to make sure that it is not overriding the OU GP. Doubt that's it, but worth a check.

Comment: I believe the default is 20 minutes on 2003; `dcdiag` and `replmon` would help diagnose any DC-to-DC errors.

Comment: I have some new news. First off, This has been a problem for a long time. So, I know that all the computers have had the chance to pull this GPO. 

Secondly, I went gpmc and did a GP Modeling... It said that GPO was denied because of security filtering. So I changed that to allow everyone.

When I re-ran this query, it got denied again, but it says reason denied, "Empty"

Comment: One more thing... should this GPO be targeted to users or computers?

Comment: WSUS is a Computer setting. How much have you changed the security setting in GPMC? It's a rare occasion that the defaults aren't good enough.

Comment: The only thing I ever changed was security filtering. Everything else seems ok.

Comment: 1- Are other GPO's working ?
2- Make sure that the security on the wsus GPO has inlcuded the Authenticated Users Group- this includes both computers and users.

Comment: There are 2 other GPO's that are working. They are domain wide GPO's. Just my wsus one is not working which is applied to just 1 OU with only computers inside of that OU. In GPMC 

When checking in GPMC on my domain server, I see that the policy is accepted on computer configuration summary, but is denied in user configuration summary (empty). I did a gpupdate /force and it reset all of my setting and it now has nothing set.  

When I run gpresult /r - It does not mention anything about my wsus policy on there.

Answer (score 1):

Change the security filtering on the GPO to apply to Domain Computers, **not** Authenticated Users.
[image: Not this]
<sub>(source: [grouppolicy.biz](http://www.grouppolicy.biz/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/image_thumb7.png))</sub>